# Trying to uninstall a program with wmic and getting error 1603

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer, uninstallation

I'm try to create a batch file that will, among other things like installing the newest version of our software, first UNINSTALL the old version. I have used "wmic product get name" to find the actual name of the program, and then I have scripted the following code to uninstall the program:

```
wmic product where "name like 'Borland CaliberRM 10.1'" call uninstall /nointeractive >> C:\users\pbrandvold\Desktop\log.txt
```

When it's finished, I get this message:

```
Executing (\\PHIL-BRANDVOLD\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Product.IdentifyingNumber="{ED8B0A1F-8E90-478A-82B6-7C885A628257}",Name="Borland CaliberRM 10.1",Version="10.1.0.84")->Uninstall()

Method execution successful.

Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
    ReturnValue = 1603;
};
```

I can't think of what is happening - why won't this uninstall? I've also tried using the msi, and running:

```
msiexec.exe /qn /x "Borland CaliberRM 10.1.msi"
```

Which doesn't work either.

Comment: You need to enable logging ( /l*v uninstall.log" ) and see what it says.

Comment: You need to run your `wmic` script (or `msiexec` as well) elevated (_Run ad Administrator_). Also ensure that software to uninstall is not curretly running (`taskkill` it if so).

Comment: Search the registry to find the 'Uninstall String'. If I remember right it will be in HHLM\SOFTWARE\\[Wow6432Node\\]Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall.

Comment: The uninstall string in the registry is not relevant. It's not used for MSI prroducts. And 1603 is often the sign of a failing custom action.

Comment: I'm running everything in an elevated command prompt, or running batch files as admin, but it doesn't seem to matter. Also, the uninstall string throws an error. I'm not running into issues when I run it without /qn, though - which is strange.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when trying to uninstall and reinstall Web Deploy using wmic via a batch file. It did not help running the batch file with elevated privileges.

The only way I could get it to run correctly was to open a Command Prompt window with elevated privileges and run the batch file through that.

The solution I ended up going with was to turn my batch file into an executable using a Bat to Exe converter. http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php

Answer (score -2):

The issue occurs due to the user's privileged of uninstalling the program.
Just open the command prompt as 'Run as administrator and run your command to uninstall the program.
Example :
open cmd with admin:
run below commands

1. wmic
2. product get name
3. product where name="YOUR_PROGRAM_NAME" call uninstall